# How to close JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have the main application frame. If user clicks the button he gets a new frame which has some chart in it. Now if I want to close that chart both chart and main application closes. How can I distinguish those two closings. Certainly I don't want my application to be closed after closing the frame in which I put chart.
Here's the code of the chart frame.

```
chartBttn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                final ShowChart sc = new ShowChart("Reserve Selection", getUtilExperiments() );
                sc.pack();
                RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(sc);
                sc.setVisible(true);
                sc.setDefaultCloseOperation(ShowChart.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

            }
        });
```

Comment: To "close the chart", do you use the window's close button or a custom close button within the window?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `dispose()` method. Or you can call `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` on the JFrame.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly on your new JFrame build a method for your close button or X window button with:

```
setVisible(false); 
dispose();
```

Otherwise please post your code on creating the new JFrame etc.

Answer (score 3):

> Certainly I don't want my application to be closed after closing the frame in which I put chart.

1) don't create lots of `JFrames` on the fly, create `JFrame` only once and re-use that for next usage(s), then

- call only for visibility `setVisible(false/true)` with `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)`

or very simple workaround

- `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE)`

2) or `JDialog` with `setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`

3) **NOTICE:** but in this case  isn't possible close the current JVM instance, you have to add `JButton or JMenu/JMenuItem` which accelerate for `System.exit(1)`

Answer (score 0):

simply use `super.dispose();` for closing previous jframe